# FastAPI: Exception handler not running logging as instructed

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a basic logger set up using the `logging` library in Python 3.10.4. I'm attempting to make the FastAPI exception handler log any exceptions it handles, to no avail. The handler is running, as I can see that my custom Response is returned, but no log.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='mylan.log')
logger = logging.getLogger("MyLAN")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
discord_handler = DiscordHandler(webhook_url, agent, notify_users=notify_users, emit_as_code_block=False, max_size=2000)

# Add log level to handlers
discord_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add format to handlers
discord_handler.setFormatter(FORMAT)

# Add the handlers to the Logger
logger.addHandler(discord_handler)

logger.debug("Logger created")

app = FastAPI()
logger.debug('test') # This works
@app.exception_handler(Exception)
def handle_exception(req, exc):
    logger.debug("Something's brokey") # This does not
    return Response("Internal Server Error Test", status_code=500)
```

I can also confirm that the logger works, as it logs a simple message on startup which is saved successfully.

I'm not even getting any errors in stdout that might guide me towards a solution.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please update your question to include sufficient code to reproduce the problem. Where are you enabling debug logging? Where is the `exception_handler` decorator? If we can use the code in your question to quickly reproduce the behavior you're asking about, you'll get better answers (and probably faster answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me as written. Here's the code I tested. It's basically identical to what you have, but it's runnable, and includes a `/error` route that raises a `KeyError` to test the exception handler:

```
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from discord_handler import DiscordHandler

webhook_url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/..."

logging.basicConfig(filename="mylan.log")
logger = logging.getLogger("MyLAN")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
discord_handler = DiscordHandler(
    webhook_url,
    "Example",
    notify_users=[],
    emit_as_code_block=True,
    max_size=2000,
)

# Add log level to handlers
discord_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add the handlers to the Logger
logger.addHandler(discord_handler)

logger.debug("Logger created")

app = FastAPI()
logger.debug("test")  # This works


@app.exception_handler(Exception)
def handle_exception(req, exc):
    logger.debug("Something's broken")  # This does not
    return Response("Internal Server Error Test", status_code=500)


@app.get("/error")
def error():
    raise KeyError("example")
```

When this code starts up, I see in my discord channel:

```
Logger created...
test...
```

And when I make a request to `/error`, I see:

```
Something's broken...
```